# How to get shopify access token without code using hmac

Tags: node.js, shopify

I'm trying to get access token using hamc,timestamp and signature but I was not able to get, due to not proper documentation of shopify how to refresh access token once it will be invalid.Is there any way to get valid token without reauthorize the users using previous account details.I'm able to get access token using code like this

```
var tokenUrl = 'https://' + req.body.code.account + '/admin/oauth/access_token';
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: tokenUrl,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-URIencoded'
    },
    form: {
        code: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',  //If the code is not available , what will be the parameter
        client_id: result.keyData.client_id,
        client_secret: result.keyData.secret_key
    }
};
```

But what will be the parameter if the code is not available

Comment: The access-token stays valid always till the user uninstalls the App. There is no need to refresh the token. May i know why do you need to refresh access-token?

Comment: Yes ,I used online access mode for some reason and in that mode we need to refresh our access token once it will become invalid